# How to create AMI from existing EC2 instance with tags from AWS CLI?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm trying to create a new AMI from my existing EC2 instance with tags. I tried the following command but it doesn't work:

```
aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-xxxxxxxxxxxxx --name "TEST_AMI" --no-reboot --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=name,Value=TEST_AMI}
```

and its return following error:

```
**usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:
  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
Unknown options: --tag-specifications, ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=name,Value=TEST_AMI}]**
```

I just need to do both tasks in one command.

Answer (score 0):

The value for the `ResourceType` is invalid. From create-image [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-image.html):

The tags to apply to the AMI and snapshots on creation. You can tag the AMI, the snapshots, or both.

- To tag the AMI, the value for ResourceType must be `image`.
- To tag the snapshots that are created of the root volume and of other Amazon EBS volumes that are attached to the instance, the value for ResourceType must be `snapshot`. The same tag is applied to all of the snapshots that are created.

Comment: I tried Image as well. but Its returning same error.